# Custom Neo4j High Availability

Tags: neo4j, cluster-computing, high-availability

I was curious if it's possible to create an HA cluster of Neo4j ***without*** using Neo4j Enterprise edition. The reason being that the Enterprise license can be a bit pricey. Has anyone ever done some sort of work around?

Comment: I'm not sure so I won't post an answer, but the docs on how to set up an HA cluster specify that you have to start with the Enterprise edition.  So I assume it requires Enterprise (but not sure).   http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html

Comment: Yes HA is only available in Enterprise Edition. For PHP developers, NeoClient provides a replication mode and slave fallback capability with Neo4jCommunity. https://github.com/neoxygen/neo4j-neoclient

Comment: I'd check with Neo Technology directly, as this is about licensing and not programming. They have special [licensing](http://neo4j.com/subscriptions/) arrangements for individuals and startups so, again, you should be talking directly with them.

Comment: Yes you should ask first before dismissing it there are lots of options available.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **NO**.

From the [Neo4j docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha.html):

> The High Availability features **are only available in the Neo4j Enterprise Edition**.

But, with that said - it is possible to use other alternatives.

I have used an [eventual consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) pattern to work out a HA-solution. The solution does not support `ACID` but that is needed for my requirements.

The solution is a queue-based solution. All modifying changes (i.e. queries that modifies the db) are placed on a distributed queue. Each database instance in the cluster has a worker process in front of it that reads messages from the queue and updates the database.

The user sessions are *sticky* so a users reads from the same database throughout their entire session (or until the server fails/restarts). This makes the user experience better since when data is inconsistent between the databases (normally just for a second or two) the user still gets the *known* data.

Comment: Would be cool if you blogged about that somewhere, might be also interesting for other people.